# excel column type Date format problems in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark

[image]

when i read an excel file in pandas dataframe i got this strange format date i want to get rid of the zeros

'''
dataframes.append(pd.read_excel(full_excel_path,sheet_name=sheet_name,engine='openpyxl',header=header,usecols=usecols,nrows=nrows,dtype=str))

```
for object in json_meta_data:

    header = object['excel_header'] - 1
    excel_filename = object['excel_filename']
    sheet_name = object['excel_sheet_name']
    usecols = object['excel_usecols']
    nrows = object['excel_nrows']
```

'''

Comment: That's the time component of your datetime.

Comment: If you like an answer please check it and upvote it. If the answer does not work please provide more details of what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the dtype. Pandas has a to_datetime that is good for this.
example `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.date`

For your column you might use
`df['date_arrete'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_arrete']).dt.date`